# Motivation behind the conjugate Schrödinger equation

Tags: probability, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

What is our motivation behind the conjugate Schrödinger equation (SE), mathematically a conjugate complex scalar is a "projection" of that complex scalar on its opposite quadrant. But what's going on with SE?
I mean, the time-dependent part turns negative, phisically, what does it means? Are we projecting the SE with a "time inversion SE" when we want to find the probability density?

Comment: Possible duplicate on Physics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102838/195139

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question on context-free languages from Sipser's computation book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102797/a-question-on-context-free-languages-from-sipsers-computation-book)